# Loading UIImage in CollectionView Cell movement freezes

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionViewCell with 1 to 3 UIImageView that are managed by a stackView.

The Images all have around 8mb. I load them async from CoreData before calling collectionView.reload()

In this setup the collection view freezes when moving while loading new cells.

I tried it with smaller Images and then it did not freeze.

I now scale the Images down before loading them in to the UIImageView. But it leads to other weird behaviour like first showing the picture from the other cell and then adding the correct ones.

```
override func configureCellAtIndexPath(item: Journaling) {
        super.configureCellAtIndexPath(item: item)

        let imageOne = UIImageView()
        let imageTwo = UIImageView()
        let imageThree = UIImageView()
        imageContainer = nil
        imageOne.image = nil
        imageTwo.image = nil
        imageThree.image = nil


        if item.image.count == 1 {
            let group = DispatchGroup()
            group.enter()
            var downsizedImage = [UIImage]()
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                downsizedImage.append(item.image[0].downsizeImage(.low)!)

                group.leave()
            }

            group.notify(queue: .main) {
                imageOne.image = downsizedImage[0]
                imageTwo.image = nil
                imageThree.image = nil
                self.setUpStackView([imageOne])
            }
        }

        if item.image.count == 2 {
            let group = DispatchGroup()
            group.enter()
            var downsizedImage = [UIImage]()
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                downsizedImage.append(item.image[0].downsizeImage(.low)!)
                downsizedImage.append(item.image[1].downsizeImage(.low)!)
                group.leave()
            }

            group.notify(queue: .main) {
                imageOne.image = downsizedImage[0]
                imageTwo.image = downsizedImage[1]
                imageThree.image = nil
                self.setUpStackView([imageOne,imageTwo])
            }


        }

        if item.image.count > 2 {
            let group = DispatchGroup()
            group.enter()
            var downsizedImage = [UIImage]()
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                downsizedImage.append(item.image[0].downsizeImage(.low)!)
                downsizedImage.append(item.image[1].downsizeImage(.low)!)
                downsizedImage.append(item.image[2].downsizeImage(.low)!)

                group.leave()
            }

            group.notify(queue: .main) {
                imageOne.image = downsizedImage[0]
                imageTwo.image = downsizedImage[1]
                imageThree.image = downsizedImage[2]
                self.setUpStackView([imageOne,imageTwo,imageThree])
            }
        }

        imageOne.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageOne.clipsToBounds = true
        imageTwo.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageTwo.clipsToBounds = true
        imageThree.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageThree.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    func setUpStackView(_ views: [UIView]) {
        self.imageContainer = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: views)
        self.imageContainer.axis = .horizontal
        self.imageContainer.distribution = .fillEqually

        placeholder.sv(imageContainer)
        imageContainer.addConstrainsToSuperView(distance: 0, superView: placeholder)

    }
```

Comment: Try implementing prepareForReuse() method in your collection view cell class and set all imageView image to nil

Comment: Memory use is NOT related to file size! It's about the dimentions of the image. You should consider prefered dimention and also cache images after resize.

Comment: These are images chosen by the user. How woulf you handle the problem?

Comment: @milan the weird behavior i could resolve.

Comment: Would you tackle the dimension problem differently?

Comment: @PaFi If collection view freezing is the only problem then fetch your image from CoreData using background thread and update your imageview in main thread
eg: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
           let image =  // fetch your image from core data
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.yourImageview.image = image
            }
        }

Comment: I am fetching the images from core data im a background thread already, but thanks